How to add a modal keymap inside of a created keymap

import bpy

window_manager = bpy.context.window_manager

def get_keymap_items_ctx(keymap_config: str , keymap_context: str):
    return window_manager.keyconfigs[keymap_config].keymaps[keymap_context].keymap_items

def remove_keymap(keymap_items_context, idname):
    keymap_item = keymap_items_context.get(idname)
    if keymap_item:
        keymap_items_context.remove(keymap_item)
    else:
        print(f"KeyMapItem {idname} not found")

def add_keymap_attrs(keymap_items_context, 
                     idname: str, 
                     event_type: str, 
                     value_key, 
                     any=False, 
                     shift=0, 
                     ctrl=0, 
                     alt=0, 
                     oskey=0, 
                     key_modifier='NONE', 
                     direction='ANY', 
                     repeat=False, 
                     head=False,
                     modal_dict=None,  # New argument for modal keymap entries
                     **kwargs):

    # Create the main keymap item
    keymap_added = keymap_items_context.new(
        idname,
        event_type,
        value_key,
        any=any,
        shift=shift,
        ctrl=ctrl,
        alt=alt,
        oskey=oskey,
        key_modifier=key_modifier,
        direction=direction,
        repeat=repeat,
        head=head
    )

    # Set properties for the keymap item
    for prop_key, prop_value in kwargs.items():
        if hasattr(keymap_added.properties, prop_key):
            setattr(keymap_added.properties, prop_key, prop_value)


    return keymap_added

# Map Object Mode
km = get_keymap_items_ctx('Blender',  'Object Mode')
add_keymap_attrs(km, 'transform.translate', 'SPACE', 'PRESS')

This is a function I wrote to deal with user created keymaps, ontop of that, I would like it to change the modal keymaps


Through bpy I would like to dynamically change these kinds of shortcuts.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMapItems.html#bpy.types.KeyMapItems.new_modal
This is something I assumed I had to use but it didn't seem to work.
Did anyone ever make a solution for this? Or could anyone perhaps help me with a solution/new function similar to add_keymap_attrs

Something approximately like this should work, or at least get you nearly there.
import bpy

C = bpy.context

wm = C.window_manager
kc = wm.keyconfigs['Blender']

# Transform modal hotkeys found under this keymap
km = kc.keymaps['Transform Modal Map']


# modal dict with:
# key = propvalue to change
# value = new letter to assign

modal_dict = {
    "AXIS_X": "X",
    "AXIS_Y": "Y",
    "AXIS_Z": "Z"
    }

for item in km.keymap_items:
    pv = item.propvalue
    try:       
       new_letter = modal_dict[pv]       
    except KeyError:
        continue
    item.type = new_letter
     
    
        


On a functional level this is absolutely fantastic, I did not know that Transform Modal Map was in it's own keymap, I thought it was the child of the keymap that you were in haha.
what do you usually do to figure out what the API allows you to fill in in the cases of things like 'AXIS_X' ? I assume some print(dir()) function?

Yeah, I think I just went through and did a for item in km.keymap_items: print(item.propvalue) to see the name of each possible propvalue available.
